# Alexa Node Skill Questions / Prompts

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

So after scavenging the web, I am unable to find an answer to my problem.

Basically, I want to produce the following result in Alexa, and I want to know if its possible and the direction I should be looking in on how to achieve.

Skill / Intent Init

> "Hey Alexa.. ask  to find a restaurant near me"

Prompt

> "What's your favorite cuisine?"

Response

> "Italian"

Prompt

> "Are you looking to spend a lot of money?"

Response

> "No"

The intent logic goes somewhere in the middle of this

"Okay I found a restaurant near you called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a fairly standard Alexa custom skill. Most of the Alexa examples and tutorials would show you how to do this. I suggest looking at the Amazon developer [site](http://developer.amazon.com) for their Alexa custom skill examples and tutorials, or just searching on "Alexa tutorial".

You will collecting 3 bits of information:

1. The user's location
2. The type of food
3. Expensive

These will need to be persisted between questions, so look at examples that either use a database to store the info (DynamoDB is about the easiest to use) or that persist information in the session object (this would be my recommendation).

You can either ask the user for their location using the built in city slot type, or obtain the address of the alexa device using the [device address API](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/device-address-api).

Good luck. I hope this helps give you some pointers on how/where to start.